# Angular location change resetting browser history

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, browser-history, angularjs-service, html5-history

I'm watching for a change on `$locationChangeStart`, if the user is on Step2, and they try to go to Step1 via the browser back button, I have successfully interrupted this, displayed an alert, and will continue navigating back only if the user presses OK.

However, interrupting this with the event.preventDefault actually erases the forward history.
So, if they go: `step3 -> step2 -> attempt To step 1 -> stay on step 2`.  Then step 3 is actually no longer reachable via the forward button

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            // interrupt going from step 2 to step 1
            if(toState.indexOf("step1") != -1) {
               event.preventDefault();
               // logic / modal popup here
            }
        });
    );
```

I obviously want the forward button to allow step3 to be reachable, but it isn't after event.preventDefault(), any insight?

Comment: Did you attempt to `return false;` at the end of the funtion instead of `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Yeah, that will still allow the state/route change to happen.